# Force whitespace (html entity?) at end of string (beat trim)

Tags: replace, mediawiki, trim, html-entities

How can I trick a trimming function not to remove whitespace at the end of a string?

`&nbsp;` would normally do fine but my strings are long, so I do want them to break.

Is there no html entity for whitespace?

This is not a specific coding language question (it's complicated).

It's for MediaWiki and I want to replace underscores with normal whitespace: `{{#replace:Foo_Bar.png|_| }}`

Edit: Solution: `&#x20;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{#replace:Foo_Bar.png|_|<nowiki> </nowiki>}}`     ([documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aStringFunctions#.23replace%3a))